# How do I prevent someone from switching off mobile data from control center in iOS 11 while the iPhone is locked?

Tags: ios, control-center

Till iOS 10.3, control center did not allow you to toggle mobile data from control center. Thus, if your phone was being handled by someone else, he could not switch off mobile data without locking the phone.

However, with iOS 11, mobile data switch has been added to the control center and now anyone handling my iPhone with iOS 11 can switch off mobile data. This also compromises Find my iPhone feature in a big way.

How do I prevent somone from switching off mobile data from control center?

Comment: Prevent control center from showing in lock screen altogether, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Do not worry, it is still possible.The way is a little long. Just follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings > General > Restrictions
2. If you have setup Restrictions, enter your Restrictions passcode. If you have not set it up yet, enter a password (twice) and enable Restrictions. Make sure you will never forget this passcode; it is required even when resetting the phone. If you forget it, not only will you be disallowed from entering the Restrictions section, you will also not be able to reset your iPhone.
3. On Restrictions page, go down to the “Allow Changes” section and click on “Mobile Data”.
4. Set “Mobile Data” to “Don’t Allow Changes”. Leave the “Data Plan” to “Allow Changes”.
5. Open control center once and close it.

Now, the control center widget will not toggle mobile data and you can still go to settings and disable it while the iPhone is unlocked; just like you were doing till iOS 10.3

Comment: You still can disable mobile data by toggling 'Airplane mode'.